# how to change setTimeout time with a given time array

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout

```
<div id="show"></div>

<script>

var s = document.getElementById("show");

//let say given time array is:
//time will be 1:00,2:30,3:50 so on.....
//we need to convert time in millisecond....

var gtime = new Array("915000", "750000", "605000");

//just want to put in For loop

for(var i=0, i > 3, i++){

//put time array here

setTimeout(function(){
  s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + //put time each array here.toString();
}, //put time each array here);

}
</script>
```

> Just like in FOR LOOP:
>
> Ist LOOP setTimeout(function(){
>         s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + //put time each array here.toString();
>       }, 915000);
>
> 2nd LOOP setTimeout(function(){
>         s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + //put time each array here.toString();
>       }, 750000);
>
> 3rd LOOP setTimeout(function(){
>         s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + //put time each array here.toString();
>       }, 605000);

Comment: Chnage `i>3` to `i<3` and put `gtime[i]` in second parameter of timout

Comment: for (var i=0, i < 3, i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + " " + gtime[i];
  }, gtime[i]);
}

Answer (score 1):

Your loop to get the time is incorrect,you can use `var i in gtime` and `gtime[i])` to get the actual time.

Note: 
You need another parameter to get the right time inside the `setTimeout()` function

```js
var s = document.getElementById("show");

//let say given time array is:
//time will be 1:00,2:30,3:50 so on.....
//we need to convert time in millisecond....

var gtime = new Array("9150", "7500", "6050");

var j = 0;

for(var i in gtime){

//put time array here

   setTimeout(function(){
     $("#show").html(gtime[j]);
     j++;
   },Number(gtime[i]));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Time value: <div id="show"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script>

var s = document.getElementById("show");

//let say given time array is:
//time will be 1:00,2:30,3:50 so on.....
//we need to convert time in millisecond....

var gtime = new Array("915000", "750000", "605000");

//just want to put in For loop

for(var i=0, i < 3, i++){

//put time array here

setTimeout(function(){
  s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + gtime[i];
}, gtime[i]);

}
</script>
```